# Unexpected: Is Pandas DataFrame a slice of its former self?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, variable-assignment, slice

I intended to drop all rows in a dataframe that I no longer need using the following:

```
df = df[my_selection]
```

where `my_selection` is a series of boolean values.

Later when I tried to add a column as follows:

```
df['New column'] = pd.Series(data)
```

I got the well-known `"SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"`

Does this mean that `df` is actually a slice of its former self?

Or why am I being accused of assigning values to a slice?

Demo code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': pd.Series(range(8)),
    'B': pd.Series(range(8,0,-1))
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  0  8
1  1  7
2  2  6
3  3  5
4  4  4
5  5  3
6  6  2
7  7  1
```

This causes a warning:

```
my_selection = df['A'] < 4
df = df[my_selection]
df['C'] = pd.Series(range(4))
```

This does not create a warning:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['C'] = pd.Series(range(8))
```

Should I be using df.drop?

Comment: Check out [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Yes, df is a slice taken out of the original df. Just tell pandas you are aware of what you are doing by `df = df[my_selection].copy()`

Comment: Thanks @Akshay. So it is 'false positive' warning then?  Other than disabling this warning is there a more friendly way to avoid it?

Comment: @ayhan that sounds good but will it duplicate the dataframe in memory?  Or will the old one get garbage collected?

Comment: That generates a copy either way. By using `df df[myselection].copy()` you are sending a signal that it is an explicit copy so of course the changes will not be reflected in the original one. You can achieve the same with `df.is_copy = None` after taking the slice. You are overwriting the original df and there is no name pointing to the original df anymore so yeah, it will be collected by garbage collector.